# Virtual hosts no longer work after WAMP reinstallation

Tags: php, apache, wamp, virtualhost

My virtual hosts no longer work after i reinstalled WAMP recently and yet i modified all the files that needed to be edited.

**In C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc :**

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       localhost-yummy.com
127.0.0.1       localhost-costa.com
127.0.0.1       local-portail.com
```

**C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf:**

```
#
# Virtual Hosts
#
# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.

#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
NameVirtualHost *:80

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/apache2/docs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/apache2/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>



<VirtualHost *:80>     
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/Yummy/dev/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost-yummy.com
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    <Directory "C:/wamp/www/Yummy/dev/htdocs">
        #AllowOverride All
        #Allow from all
        #Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>     
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>     
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/Costa-Puzzle/dev/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost-costa.com
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    <Directory "C:/wamp/www/Costa-Puzzle/dev/htdocs">
        #AllowOverride All
        #Allow from all
        #Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>     
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/portailmg/dev/htdocs"
    ServerName local-portail.com
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    <Directory "C:/wamp/www/portailmg/dev/htdocs">
        #AllowOverride All
        #Allow from all
        #Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When i type for instance : local-portail.com

i have the following screen:

http://hpics.li/d56c088

Comment: Have you tried switching it off and on again (have you rebooted or restarted wamp after you made your changes)

Comment: Hello, yes, i tried to restart all services many times ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you've set up the hosts file and vhosts config file correctly. However, in order for Apache to even load in the httpd-vhosts.conf file you need to uncomment a line in the C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.17\conf\httpd.conf file. There should be a line like this:

```
#Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

You need to uncomment this line and restart the server. Then Apache should look at the vhosts config file and it should work!

Comment: Thanks, i just did it , seems things are a bit different now but when i type local-portail.com i have an internal server error : i checked the apache error log : "[Thu May 30 12:14:49 2013] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/wamp/www/portailmg/dev/htdocs/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration"

Comment: just had to uncomment LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so